# How to create transaction for commands that not written in the same field of event or method

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, transactions

Pardon me , this is the first time when I am using satackoverflow I face a problem and I've searched a lot but my problem didn't solved.
I have a program that is built using MVC programming in C# .. A data access layer has a function called ExecuteCommand that performs the the execution of Queries .. in other hand in business layer I have the methods that contains the call of the method ExecuteCommand to execute the stored procedure after taking its parameters values .. and finally In some tool events I call the method to perform its function such that in button Click event , I've used transaction before in my projects when I was writing the queries inside the events directly but in this case I don't know how to do it .. I'll put my code samples for more explain it will be the codes for receipting a company cash and updating the debt of the company

ExecuteCommand method in data access layer:

```
public void executeCommand(string storedProcedure,SqlParameter[] param)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            if (param != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
                }
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

insert company receipt method in Business layer code:

```
public void InsertCompRcptInfo(DateTime rcptDate, string userName, int compID, string compName, string compDelegate, double amount)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@rcptDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            param[0].Value = rcptDate;
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            param[1].Value = userName;
            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@compID", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[2].Value = compID;
            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@compName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40);
            param[3].Value = compName;
            param[4] = new SqlParameter("@compDelegate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
            param[4].Value = compDelegate;
            param[5] = new SqlParameter("@amount", SqlDbType.SmallMoney);
            param[5].Value = amount;
            DAL.executeCommand("InsertCompRcptInfo", param);
            DAL.close();
        }
```

update company debt method in Business layer code:

```
public void UpdateCompDebt(int compID, string compName,int pBillNo, double pending, double paid)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@compID", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[0].Value = compID;
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@compName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40);
            param[1].Value = compName;
            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@pBillNo", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[2].Value = pBillNo;
            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@pending", SqlDbType.SmallMoney);
            param[3].Value = pending;
            param[4] = new SqlParameter("@paid", SqlDbType.SmallMoney);
            param[4].Value = paid;
            DAL.executeCommand("UpdateCompDebt", param);
            DAL.close();
        }
```

button click event in the form code:

```
 private void compRcptSaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double payment = Convert.ToInt32(compRcptAmountTxt.Text);
            rcpt.InsertCompRcptInfo(Convert.ToDateTime(compRcptDateLbl.Text), user, Convert.ToInt32(compRcpCompCmbo.SelectedValue), compRcpCompCmbo.Text, compRcptDelegateTxt.Text, Convert.ToDouble(compRcptAmountTxt.Text));
            dtFindDebt = rcpt.FindCompDebt(Convert.ToInt32(compRcpCompCmbo.SelectedValue), compRcpCompCmbo.Text);
            for(int i=0;i<dtFindDebt.Rows.Count;i++)
            {  
                if(payment>0)
                {
                    double pending = Convert.ToDouble(dtFindDebt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
                    if (payment >= pending)
                    {
                        double paid = pending;
                        payment = payment - pending;
                        pending = 0;
                        rcpt.UpdateCompDebt(Convert.ToInt32(compRcpCompCmbo.SelectedValue), compRcpCompCmbo.Text, Convert.ToInt32(dtFindDebt.Rows[i][0].ToString()), pending, paid);              
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        double paid = payment;
                        pending=pending-payment;
                        rcpt.UpdateCompDebt(Convert.ToInt32(compRcpCompCmbo.SelectedValue), compRcpCompCmbo.Text, Convert.ToInt32(dtFindDebt.Rows[i][0].ToString()), pending, paid);              
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain

Comment: @Paddy any help !!